# How do you correctly implement the function for shifting UITextFields above the users input, when it obscures the UITextField?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, uitextfield

Upon finding Apple's documentation for `UITextFields`, [I stumbled upon this article](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/TextAndWebiPhoneOS/KeyboardManagement/KeyboardManagement.html) which details how one can make it so that a `UITextField`, housed within a `UIScrollView`, can be shifted upwards so that the user can view their input. However, whenever I try to implement this, the behaviour is never as described. It either does nothing or shifts everything downwards, regardless of which `UITextField` you choose to edit.

**Here is my code, can someone diagnose it?:**

```
#import "FourthViewController.h"
@import Firebase;
@import FirebaseAuth;
@import FirebaseDatabase;

@interface FourthViewController ()
{
    UITextField *activeField;
}
@property (strong, nonatomic) FIRDatabaseReference *ref;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *logoutButton;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIScrollView *scrollView;
@property (readonly, nonatomic, nullable) FIRApp *app;
@property (readonly, strong, nonatomic, nullable) FIRUser *currentUser;
@property(weak, nonatomic) NSArray *countryArray;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *usernameEntry;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *forenameEntry;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *surnameEntry;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *emailAddressEntry;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *countryEntry;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *homeAddressEntry;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *applyChangesButton;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *profilePictureEntry;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *emailValidationCheck;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIPickerView *countrySelector;


@end

@implementation FourthViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.ref = [[FIRDatabase database] reference];
    FIRUser *user = [FIRAuth auth].currentUser;

    if (user)
    {
        [[[[_ref child: @"Users"] child:user.uid] child:@"Username"] observeSingleEventOfType:FIRDataEventTypeValue withBlock:^(FIRDataSnapshot *snapshot)
        {
            if (snapshot.exists)
            {
                _usernameEntry.text = snapshot.value;
            }
        }];

        _emailAddressEntry.text = user.email;
    }

    _countrySelector.delegate = self;
    _countrySelector.dataSource = self;

    self.logoutButton.layer.cornerRadius= 8;
    self.logoutButton.layer.borderWidth = 1.5f;
    self.logoutButton.layer.borderColor = [UIColor whiteColor].CGColor;
    [_logoutButton addTarget:self action:@selector(logoutButtonHighlightBorder) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
    [_logoutButton addTarget:self action:@selector(logoutButtonUnhighlightBorder) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [_logoutButton addTarget:self action:@selector(logoutButtonUnhighlightBorder) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDragExit];

    self.applyChangesButton.layer.cornerRadius = 8;

    _countrySelector.layer.cornerRadius = 8;

    NSLocale *locale = [NSLocale currentLocale];

    NSArray *countryArray = [NSLocale ISOCountryCodes];
    NSMutableArray *sortedCountryArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    for (NSString *countryCode in countryArray)
    {
        NSString *displayNameString = [locale displayNameForKey:NSLocaleCountryCode value:countryCode];
        [sortedCountryArray addObject:displayNameString];
    }
    [sortedCountryArray sortUsingSelector:@selector(localizedCompare:)];
}


- (IBAction)applyChanges:(UIButton *)sender
{
    NSString *userID = [FIRAuth auth].currentUser.uid;
    NSString* username = _usernameEntry.text;
    [[[_ref child:@"Users"] child:userID] setValue:@{@"Username": username}];

    [[FIRAuth auth].currentUser updateEmail:_emailAddressEntry.text
                             completion:^(NSError * _Nullable error)
     {
         if(error)
         {
             [_emailValidationCheck setTextColor:[UIColor redColor]];
             _emailValidationCheck.text = @"Email Address modification was unsuccessful";
         }
         else
         {
             [_emailValidationCheck setTextColor:[UIColor greenColor]];
             _emailValidationCheck.text = @"Email Address modification was successful";
         }
     }];
}

- (IBAction)logout:(UIButton *)sender
{
    NSError *signOutError;
    BOOL status = [[FIRAuth auth] signOut:&signOutError];
    if (!status)
    {
        NSLog(@"Error signing out: %@", signOutError);
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"Successfully Signout");
    }
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(nonnull UIPickerView *)pickerView
{
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)pickerView:(nonnull UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    return _countryArray.count;
}

- (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    return _countryArray[row];
}

- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    _countryEntry.text = _countryArray[row];
}

- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    [self.view endEditing:YES];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
}

- (UIStatusBarStyle)preferredStatusBarStyle
{
    return UIStatusBarStyleLightContent;
}

- (void)logoutButtonHighlightBorder
{
    _logoutButton.layer.borderColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.61 green:0.00 blue:0.02 alpha:1.0].CGColor;
}

- (void)logoutButtonUnhighlightBorder
{
    _logoutButton.layer.borderColor = [UIColor whiteColor].CGColor;
}

- (void)registerForKeyboardNotifications
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(keyboardWasShown:)

 name:UIKeyboardDidShowNotification object:nil];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                      selector:@selector(keyboardWillBeHidden:)

 name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification object:nil];

}

- (void)keyboardWasShown:(NSNotification*)aNotification
{
    NSDictionary* info = [aNotification userInfo];
     CGSize kbSize = [[info objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] CGRectValue].size;
    CGRect bkgndRect = activeField.superview.frame;
    bkgndRect.size.height += kbSize.height;
    [activeField.superview setFrame:bkgndRect];
    [_scrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0.0, activeField.frame.origin.y-kbSize.height) animated:YES];
}

- (void)keyboardWillBeHidden:(NSNotification*)aNotification
{
    UIEdgeInsets contentInsets = UIEdgeInsetsZero;
    _scrollView.contentInset = contentInsets;
    _scrollView.scrollIndicatorInsets = contentInsets;
}

- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    activeField = textField;
}

- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    activeField = nil;
}
```

Updated Code:

```
#import "FourthViewController.h"
@import Firebase;
@import FirebaseAuth;
@import FirebaseDatabase;

@interface FourthViewController ()
{
    UITextField *activeField;
}
@property (strong, nonatomic) FIRDatabaseReference *ref;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *logoutButton;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIScrollView *scrollView;
@property (readonly, nonatomic, nullable) FIRApp *app;
@property (readonly, strong, nonatomic, nullable) FIRUser *currentUser;
@property(weak, nonatomic) NSArray *countryArray;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *usernameEntry;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *forenameEntry;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *surnameEntry;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *emailAddressEntry;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *countryEntry;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *homeAddressEntry;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *applyChangesButton;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *profilePictureEntry;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *emailValidationCheck;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIPickerView *countrySelector;


@end

@implementation FourthViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.ref = [[FIRDatabase database] reference];
    FIRUser *user = [FIRAuth auth].currentUser;

    [self registerForKeyboardNotifications];

    if (user)
    {
        [[[[_ref child: @"Users"] child:user.uid] child:@"Username"] observeSingleEventOfType:FIRDataEventTypeValue withBlock:^(FIRDataSnapshot *snapshot)
        {
            if (snapshot.exists)
            {
                _usernameEntry.text = snapshot.value;
            }
        }];

        _emailAddressEntry.text = user.email;
    }

    _countrySelector.delegate = self;
    _countrySelector.dataSource = self;

    self.logoutButton.layer.cornerRadius= 8;
    self.logoutButton.layer.borderWidth = 1.5f;
    self.logoutButton.layer.borderColor = [UIColor whiteColor].CGColor;
    [_logoutButton addTarget:self action:@selector(logoutButtonHighlightBorder) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
    [_logoutButton addTarget:self action:@selector(logoutButtonUnhighlightBorder) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [_logoutButton addTarget:self action:@selector(logoutButtonUnhighlightBorder) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDragExit];

     self.applyChangesButton.layer.cornerRadius = 8;

    _countrySelector.layer.cornerRadius = 8;

     NSLocale *locale = [NSLocale currentLocale];

     NSArray *countryArray = [NSLocale ISOCountryCodes];
     NSMutableArray *sortedCountryArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
     for (NSString *countryCode in countryArray)
    {
        NSString *displayNameString = [locale displayNameForKey:NSLocaleCountryCode value:countryCode];
        [sortedCountryArray addObject:displayNameString];
    }
    [sortedCountryArray sortUsingSelector:@selector(localizedCompare:)];
}


- (IBAction)applyChanges:(UIButton *)sender
{
    NSString *userID = [FIRAuth auth].currentUser.uid;
    NSString* username = _usernameEntry.text;
    [[[_ref child:@"Users"] child:userID] setValue:@{@"Username": username}];

    [[FIRAuth auth].currentUser updateEmail:_emailAddressEntry.text
                             completion:^(NSError * _Nullable error)
     {
         if(error)
         {
             [_emailValidationCheck setTextColor:[UIColor redColor]];
             _emailValidationCheck.text = @"Email Address modification was unsuccessful";
         }
         else
         {
             [_emailValidationCheck setTextColor:[UIColor greenColor]];
             _emailValidationCheck.text = @"Email Address modification was successful";
         }
     }];
}

- (IBAction)logout:(UIButton *)sender
{
    NSError *signOutError;
    BOOL status = [[FIRAuth auth] signOut:&signOutError];
    if (!status)
    {
        NSLog(@"Error signing out: %@", signOutError);
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"Successfully Signout");
    }
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(nonnull UIPickerView *)pickerView
{
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)pickerView:(nonnull UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    return _countryArray.count;
}

- (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    return _countryArray[row];
}

- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    _countryEntry.text = _countryArray[row];
}

- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    [self.view endEditing:YES];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
}

- (UIStatusBarStyle)preferredStatusBarStyle
{
    return UIStatusBarStyleLightContent;
}

- (void)logoutButtonHighlightBorder
{
    _logoutButton.layer.borderColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.61 green:0.00 blue:0.02 alpha:1.0].CGColor;
}

- (void)logoutButtonUnhighlightBorder
{
    _logoutButton.layer.borderColor = [UIColor whiteColor].CGColor;
}

- (void)registerForKeyboardNotifications
{
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(keyboardWasShown:)

                                             name:UIKeyboardDidShowNotification object:nil];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                          selector:@selector(keyboardWillBeHidden:)

                                              name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification object:nil];
}

- (void)keyboardWasShown:(NSNotification*)aNotification
{
    NSDictionary* info = [aNotification userInfo];
    CGRect kbFrame = [[info objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] CGRectValue];
    CGFloat offset = CGRectGetMaxY(activeField.frame) - CGRectGetMinY(kbFrame);
    [_scrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0.0, offset) animated:YES];
}

- (void)keyboardWillBeHidden:(NSNotification*)aNotification
{
    UIEdgeInsets contentInsets = UIEdgeInsetsZero;
    _scrollView.contentInset = contentInsets;
    _scrollView.scrollIndicatorInsets = contentInsets;
}

- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    activeField = textField;
}

- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    activeField = nil;
}

@end
```

Comment: For additional information, none of my application's views use any constraints, therefore I require a solution that doesn't involve them, as I already have tonnes of animations that would require a complete change, if I were to implement constraints.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is shift the bottom edge of your textField directly above the keyboard. This is done by just adjusting the scrollView's contentOffset the right way. You already do it almost right as I can see. The only thing that might be wrong is that you change `CGRect bkgndRect = activeField.superview.frame;` what is not necessary. You could try the following approach where minY/maxY are frame.origin.y/(frame.origin.y+frame.size.height).

```
- (void)keyboardWillShow:(NSNotification*)aNotification
{
    NSDictionary* info = [aNotification userInfo];
    CGRect kbFrame = [[info objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] CGRectValue];
    CGFloat offset = CGRectGetMaxY(activeTextField.frame) - CGRectGetMinY(kbFrame)
    _scrollView.contentOffset = CGPointMake(0.0, offset);
}

- (void)keyboardWillHide:(NSNotification*)aNotification
{
    _scrollView.contentOffset = CGPointZero;
}
```

Additionally, you can also check if the calculated offset is > 0 since in this case, the text field is already above the keyboard.

Also when the keyboard will be hidden I think I never updated the scroll indicator insets.  Just reset the content offset of the scroll view.

If you need this code some day for Swift 4++ - here is an example for this too which does not use auto layout. Actually, I tested this code and it works:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var willShow: NSObjectProtocol?
    var willHide: NSObjectProtocol?

    let scroll = UIScrollView()
    let txt = UITextField()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.backgroundColor = .white


        scroll.frame = view.bounds
        scroll.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = true
        view.addSubview(scroll)

        txt.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: scroll.bounds.height-100, width: scroll.bounds.width, height: 50)
        txt.text = "Hello World"
        txt.backgroundColor = .lightGray
        txt.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = true
        scroll.addSubview(txt)

        willShow = NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: .UIKeyboardWillShow, object: nil, queue: .main) { (note) in
            let kbFrame = note.userInfo?[UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as? CGRect ?? .zero
            self.scroll.contentOffset = CGPoint(x: 0, y: self.txt.frame.maxY - kbFrame.minY )
        }

        willHide = NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: .UIKeyboardWillHide, object: nil, queue: .main) { (note) in
            self.scroll.contentOffset = .zero
        }

        view.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: txt, action: #selector(resignFirstResponder)))
    }
}
```

Hope that helps

Comment: Thanks for all the help, a lot of effort has gone into your thorough answer. However, I have an issue with the implementation, specifically around the minY and maxY values, how do I arrange my code to find them? "    CGRect maxY = activeField.frame.origin.y / (activeField.frame.origin.y + activeField.frame.size.height);" receives an error (regarding the value being of type 'double'). Any assistance with this?

Comment: So the offset calculated with minY/maxY can also be written as: `CGFloat offset = (activeField.frame.origin.y + activeField.frame.size.height) - kbFrame.origin.y`. MaxY is a Swift convenience way for obtaining `view.frame.origin.y + view.frame.size.height` and it is a CGFloat value. If Objective-C does not have this you can just replace it by the longer version above.

Comment: ah ok, well that minimises the errors.. haha. Last error to fix, now. For "kbFrame.origin" I get the error "'No member named 'origin' in 'struct CGSize'"

Comment: Okay I edited my long answer above. In objective-C you get minY/maxY by calling the functions `CGRectGetMinY(CGRect)` and `CGRectGetMaxY(CGRect)`. Also I changed kbFrame to be a `CGRect` and not a `CGSize`. That should solve your problems 

Comment: amended my code, the code editor doesn't register any errors now, which is good. However, I've got another problem... haha. Basically, instead of shifting everything down by a little bit, they now all fly off the screen...

Comment: can you update the code in your answer so I can see how you changed your code?

Comment: Try to use the notifications willShow and willHide and set the animation parameter in setContentOffset to false. You can do that because will show is already executed inside of an animation context. When you do so it will result in a pretty nice animation. Additionally, I see that you reset `contentInset` instead of `contentOffset` in `keyboardWillBeHidden`.

Comment: I don't think any of those solutions will help. Currently, all of the content, regardless of which UITextField is clicked, shoots off the screen, in the downwards direction.

Comment: Hm, it's really difficult to debug without the complete code. You'll find the failure ;-) I hope I could help a little bit at least!